# Jquery Data table export to Excel, Want to convert some number columns to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

[image: Data table to be exported to Excel]

[image: Excel Output]

This question might have been answered somewhere but I can't get it right yet. I have a data table that I'm exporting to Excel but my problem is the field 'Account Number' has a string like "800953". When I export to excel it's displaying "800,953".

My JS code below seems to be missing something. I had tried to put a dot in front of string then replace it with blank. The bit where it's supposed to pick the first 4 columns is working fine.

```
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.export-table').DataTable({
        fixedHeader: {
            header: true
        },
        dom: 'Bflit',
        lengthMenu: [
            [100, -1],
            ['100 rows', 'Show All']
        ],
    buttons: [
        {   
            extend: 'excel',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [1, 2, 3, 4],
                exportOptions: {
                    format: {
                        body: function (data, row, column, node) {
                            return data.replace(/\./g, ' ');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
]
    });

    $('.data-table').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]]
    });
    $('#datable_2').DataTable({ "lengthChange": false });
});
```

Comment: This can be solved, but start with upgrading to latest version 1.5.3. The excel export have been massively improved over the last year.  A few months back I had a lot of problems with multiple columns, strings, floating values, integers and so on. They were all solved "magically" by upgrading. Better than a "hack" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution to my question after going through this [thread](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/43031/how-to-convert-numbers-to-text-in-export-excel-of-jqery-datatable-plug-in).

"use strict";

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('.export-table').DataTable({
    fixedHeader: {
        header: true
    },
    dom: 'Bflit',// 'lBfrtip',// 'Bfrtip', 
    lengthMenu: [
        [100, -1],
        ['100 rows', 'Show All']
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            customize: function (xlsx) {
                var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];

                $('row c[r^="C"]', sheet).attr('s', '50'); //"C" is Account number column
            }
        }
    ]
});

$('.data-table').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]]
});
$('#datable_2').DataTable({ "lengthChange": false });
```

});